Why is a macOS build version of my iPhone app not available in the App Store Connect?
My iPhone app has been successfully uploaded to the App Store Connect and distributed to the general public. I'm now trying to port the app to macOS; I am able to test it on a Mac via TestFlight. However, when I try to submit it for distribution in App Store Connect, I don't see the option of + or Add build in the Build section. What could be the reasons that prevent the macOS build from being uploaded to the Store?
I'm using Xcode Version 16.0 (16A242d).

Customer service questions, including account management and app store issues are off topic here. See [help/on-topic]

I appreciate that you provided the reason for your down vote. Thank you for the courtesy.

Please read the tag’s descriptor before using a tag. distribution is not what you think.

@litbe.Dont make assumptions. I didn't down vote this question.

Sorry for the wrong assumption. I just felt such a gratitude toward you for pointing out my mistakes constructively.

I was able to fix this problem by enabling App Sandbox for my app in Xcode. In addition to this setting, other steps are outlined here.
